# Using document.getElementById('').innerHTML to print out an array ignores HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using `document.getElementById('').innerHTML` to print out an array from a function it turns the whole page white and all my HTML and CSS is just ignored.

the code is here:
https://github.com/tserrato/bug-free-octo-fiesta

Comment: a: you're using `document.write` ... and b: you're not returning anything inside array.reduce

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself, they should be self contained and not make users go to external sites just to see the code. If it is too large make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Using just [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you could do it like this:

```js
let movies=[{title:"The Shawshank Redemption",year:1994,director:"Frank Darabont",duration:"2h 22min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:9.3},{title:"The Godfather",year:1972,director:"Francis Ford Coppola",duration:"2h 55min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:9.2},{title:"The Godfather: Part II",year:1974,director:"Francis Ford Coppola",duration:"3h 22min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:9},{title:"The Dark Knight",year:2008,director:"Christopher Nolan",duration:"2h 32min",genre:["Action","Crime","Drama","Thriller"],rate:9},{title:"12 Angry Men",year:1957,director:"Sidney Lumet",duration:"1h 36min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:8.9},{title:'Schindler"s List',year:1993,director:"Steven Spielberg",duration:"3h 15min",genre:["Biography","Drama","History"],rate:8.9},{title:"Pulp Fiction",year:1994,director:"Quentin Tarantino",duration:"2h 34min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:8.9},{title:"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",year:2003,director:"Peter Jackson",duration:"3h 21min",genre:["Adventure","Drama","Fantasy"],rate:8.9},{title:"Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo",year:1966,director:"Sergio Leone",duration:"3h 2min",genre:["Western"],rate:8.9},{title:"Fight Club",year:1999,director:"David Fincher",duration:"2h 19min",genre:["Drama"],rate:8.8},{title:"The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",year:2001,director:"Peter Jackson",duration:"2h 58min",genre:["Adventure","Drama","Fantasy"],rate:8.8},{title:"Forrest Gump",year:1994,director:"Robert Zemeckis",duration:"2h 22min",genre:["Comedy","Drama","Romance"],rate:8.8},{title:"Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",year:1980,director:"Irvin Kershner",duration:"2h 4min",genre:["Action","Adventure","Fantasy","Sci-Fi"],rate:8.8},{title:"Inception",year:2010,director:"Christopher Nolan",duration:"2h 28min",genre:["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi","Thriller"],rate:8.8},{title:"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",year:2002,director:"Peter Jackson",duration:"2h 59min",genre:["Adventure","Drama","Fantasy"],rate:8.7},{title:'One Flew Over the Cuckoo"s Nest',year:1975,director:"Milos Forman",duration:"2h 13min",genre:["Drama"],rate:8.7},{title:"Goodfellas",year:1990,director:"Martin Scorsese",duration:"2h 26min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:8.7},{title:"The Matrix",year:1999,director:"Lana Wachowski",duration:"2h 16min",genre:["Action","Sci-Fi"],rate:8.7},{title:"Shichinin no samurai",year:1954,director:"Akira Kurosawa",duration:"3h 27min",genre:["Adventure","Drama"],rate:8.7},{title:"Star Wars",year:1977,director:"George Lucas",duration:"2h 1min",genre:["Action","Adventure","Fantasy","Sci-Fi"],rate:8.7},{title:"Cidade de Deus",year:2002,director:"Fernando Meirelles",duration:"2h 10min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:8.7},{title:"Se7en",year:1995,director:"David Fincher",duration:"2h 7min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Mystery","Thriller"],rate:8.6},{title:"The Silence of the Lambs",year:1991,director:"Jonathan Demme",duration:"1h 58min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Thriller"],rate:8.6},{title:'It"s a Wonderful Life',year:1946,director:"Frank Capra",duration:"2h 10min",genre:["Drama","Family","Fantasy"],rate:8.6},{title:"La vita è bella",year:1997,director:"Roberto Benigni",duration:"1h 56min",genre:["Comedy","Drama","War"],rate:8.6},{title:"The Usual Suspects",year:1995,director:"Bryan Singer",duration:"1h 46min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Mystery","Thriller"],rate:8.6},{title:"Léon",year:1988,director:"Luc Besson",duration:"1h 50min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Thriller"],rate:8.6},{title:"Saving Private Ryan",year:1998,director:"Steven Spielberg",duration:"2h 49min",genre:["Drama","War"],rate:8.6},{title:"Sen to Chihiro no kamikakushi",year:2001,director:"Hayao Miyazaki",duration:"2h 5min",genre:["Animation","Adventure","Family","Fantasy","Mystery"],rate:8.6},{title:"American History X",year:1998,director:"Tony Kaye",duration:"1h 59min",genre:["Crime","Drama"],rate:8.5},{title:'C"era una volta il West',year:1968,director:"Sergio Leone",duration:"2h 44min",genre:["Western"],rate:8.6},{title:"Interstellar",year:2014,director:"Christopher Nolan",duration:"2h 49min",genre:["Adventure","Drama","Sci-Fi"],rate:8.6},{title:"Psycho",year:1960,director:"Alfred Hitchcock",duration:"1h 49min",genre:["Horror","Mystery","Thriller"],rate:8.5},{title:"The Green Mile",year:1999,director:"Frank Darabont",duration:"3h 9min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Fantasy","Mystery"],rate:8.5},{title:"Casablanca",year:1942,director:"Michael Curtiz",duration:"1h 42min",genre:["Drama","Romance","War"],rate:8.5},{title:"City Lights",year:1931,director:"Charles Chaplin",duration:"1h 27min",genre:["Comedy","Drama","Romance"],rate:8.6},{title:"Intouchables",year:2011,director:"Olivier Nakache",duration:"1h 52min",genre:["Biography","Comedy","Drama"],rate:8.6},{title:"Modern Times",year:1936,director:"Charles Chaplin",duration:"1h 27min",genre:["Comedy","Drama","Family","Romance"],rate:8.5},{title:"Raiders of the Lost Ark",year:1981,director:"Steven Spielberg",duration:"1h 55min",genre:["Action","Adventure"],rate:8.5},{title:"The Pianist",year:2002,director:"Roman Polanski",duration:"2h 30min",genre:["Biography","Drama","Music","War"],rate:8.5},{title:"The Departed",year:2006,director:"Martin Scorsese",duration:"2h 31min",genre:["Crime","Drama","Thriller"],rate:8.5}];

function list() {
  const final = movies.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.title + '<br>', '')

  document.getElementById("nutts").innerHTML = final;
}
```

```css
#list {
    width: 75vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #393939;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
    <button onclick="list()"> click for list </button>
    <div id="nutts"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i run it on my end the text does not show up in the element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are overwrite the document (body) here:

```
let final = title.reduce((x, y) => {
    document.write(x + "<br/>" + y);


  })
```